# How to make index on parse-servers mongo

Tags: mongodb, parse-server

My setup is x4large ec2 instance and i am running parse-server . I have followed the procedure as explained in their github page here:

```
https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server
```

But they have not mentioned how to create / maintain indexing in mongo. So if anyone can point me in the right direction?

Comment: Maybe they don't mention it because you shouldn't need to manually mess with Mongo? THAT'S kind of  the point of Parse, as a façade to the Mongo API

Comment: Creating indexes for MongoDB should be done via the mongo shell (or using some mongo admin UI). more details can be found here: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/create-an-index/

Comment: @cricket_007 That _WAS_ a benefit of Parse, but parse-server does not manage indexes for you: "When using MongoDB with your Parse app, you need to manage your indexes yourself. You will also need to size up your database as your data grows." http://docs.parseplatform.org/parse-server/guide/